# Why don't we burn ourselves when we speak?

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics, everyday-life, estimation

In [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/426698/) we learn that sound transfers a lot more energy than heat across the medium, so why don't we burn ourselves when we speak by generating sound? Does sound reflect more easily than heat?

Comment: How much energy is involved in speaking, and how hot would it get, say, your tongue? Why would evolution come to a solution that involved burning of the entity?

Comment: @JonCuster I'm asking about the physics of it. I don't appreciate what looks to be a deliberate misunderstanding of a simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is similar to the reason we don't burn ourselves by compressing a spring. The compressed spring stores potential energy. If you stop pushing, the spring will push you away and you get it (almost) all back.

If the spring rubbed a wall as it compressed and expanded, there would be friction. Some energy would be lost as heat. You would not get it all back.

Sound is a pressure wave. Air compresses like a spring.

Comment: And as for heat?